# iphone design in photoshop which PPI has to be set 326? or 72?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ppi, iphone, android

i am working with 72PPI  for both android and iphone ..but some has been reffered 326 has to be set for iphone can i know what difference will occur? i am getting same result in 72 itself

Comment: will pixels per inch affect how your design is displayed at all? Aren't the pixels present all that counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am getting same result in 72 itself

That's because PPI settings in PhotoShop really only are applicable to printing the file on paper from software that reads the PPI meta data in the PSD.

In other words, it does't matter at all what you set the PPI to in PhotoShop when working with screen-based graphics. All that matters is the pixel dimensions of the image.

Comment: thank q now i got the answer....for printing purpose only we bother about PPI isit?

Comment: ppi = pixels per inch which means "pixels divided by inches". the only time ppi matters (and can even be calculated) is if you know how many inches there are. In computing, generally, one has no idea how many inches there are. I am typing this on a monitor which is probably 5x as wide (in inches) as my mobile phone and they both have the same pixel width. An identical image file view on each device has the exact same pixel dimensions, but one is obviously smaller in inches...

Comment: And to horatio's point, you have no control over PPI on a device (especially outside of iOS land where device screen inch dimensions can vary wildly). You do, however, know how many pixels total there are on the device, hence, that's the key number (the pixel dimensions).